# MSG.exe Error 5 getting session names

Tags: networking, command-line, windows-7, active-directory

I am trying to send a message through the command line using `msg.exe` on Windows 7. I have successfully gotten everything to work except for the Session ID. I get the error `Error 5 getting session names`. After searching online I found that I can edit the registry to remove this error using regedit.exe. However, on the domain I am on, **I do not have permissions to edit the registry. I can only view it**.

I know the individual session ID's of the users that I am trying to send a message to.

Super user hasn't really been any help... How do I prevent the error from occurring without editing the registry?

Answer (score 2):

You need to log into the user, that the computer you are trying to send to is on.You will need to do is go to credential manager, and add the credentials. That error message will go away.